# What is basic different between Openstack API & CLI commands for begineer's perspective?

Tags: api, command-line-interface, openstack

I am learning Openstack.. I am very confused by Openstack API & CLI !! I need to know what is difference & what is usage of both !!

regds
vadan

Comment: check out the -debug flag on the CLI, and you can see the API calls the CLI makes.

Answer (score 1):

API is Application Programming Interface, for OpenStack services, they are all ReST API, which means you need to construct http request then post to specific endpoint, then get the http response and analyze it. To directly interactive with it, you will need special tools, like RestClient, Postman or curl. API is processed by OpenStack process (sometimes is Apache process) which do the real CRUD works.

OpenStack provides some Python Binding SDK for developer to use, to simply the construct and analyze steps. You can use these SDK in your new developed OpenStack services or write some script so you can run them again and again. For example:

```
from novaclient import client
nc = client.Client(2, 'username', 'password', 'projectname', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000')
print nc.servers.list()
```

CLI is Command Line Interface, they behavior like normal linux command, then use the SDK and do http interactive with OpenStack services via API. So you can just type simple "nova list" to get all nova instances (need to export OS environment var first). CLI is processed by linux shell

Answer (score 0):

Ok .. From my experience API's are more flexible and better if you want program something lets say a NFV, and you can pass it by a python Restful API, .. The CLI in Openstack, yeah you can script a lot of stuff but its more admin commands for lets say revoking a floating ip ( It may be not applicable on GUI's). So Openstack CLi is not a Linux terminal, it's just a bunch of service programs that can control your Openstack ( check Openstack documentation ). Always remember the APi is for programming and linking other interfaces to have access to your Openstack, your CLi is usually your Admin area